# How to wrap event-driven code with callbacks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm using a third-party sockets library, although this is somewhat irrelevant to my question. The library consists of a "Socket" class with methods such as "ConnectAsync" and "WriteAsync". Control returns immediately after calling one of these methods, and the socket class raises events to notify when an operation has completed, e.g. "ConnectCompleted" and "WriteCompleted". The class also raises an event when data is received: "PacketArrived".

In my app I want to send data and wait for a reply. As this can happen in numerous places, it makes sense to wrap the above socket class in some kind of helper that does all this for me. I would also like it to be asynchronous, so the UI (WPF) doesn't freeze during the connect/write/wait for reply, so the helper method call might look something like this:-

```
SocketHelper.SendData(dataToSend, myCallback);
```

Where "myCallback" is called when data has been received.

Being new to threading, I'm not sure how to write this helper - somehow it needs to string together the various methods and events, i.e. open the connection, wait for the connection to be completed, write the data, wait for the write to complete, then wait for a data packet to arrive (then call the supplied callback). Any help appreciated.

Comment: Start by reading a primer on c# events and delegates http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html I think wrapping the library may be a bridge too far, you don't need to go passing callbacks around with the .NET eventing mechanism.

Comment: Which framework version? .NET 4 has the Task Parallel Library to help with such issues

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is .Net 4

Comment: @JeffWatkins there are multiple places in my app where it'll be sending data so I don't want to have to handle the multitude of socket events each time. Encapsulating the connect-send-receive functionality within a single method seemed like a clean approach, with a callback to say that it has received the data to keep the UI responsive while the method is executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update - November 1, 2021**

Most of the original techniques are available as methods out of the box in .NET Framework 4.7 and later, and .NET Core (which includes .NET 5 and later). At this point .NET 6 is supported in production and the current long-term support of .NET, with the full RTM in two weeks.

- The [SocketTaskExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions?view=net-5.0) class provides task-based extensions methods for Sockets, eg [ConnectAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions.connectasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_SocketTaskExtensions_ConnectAsync_System_Net_Sockets_Socket_System_String_System_Int32_) allows opening a connection asynchronously, while [SendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions.sendasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_SocketTaskExtensions_SendAsync_System_Net_Sockets_Socket_System_ReadOnlyMemory_System_Byte__System_Net_Sockets_SocketFlags_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) sends a buffer asynchronously :

```
await socket.ConnectAsync(someIp,somePort);
await socket.Send(msg, SocketFlags.None);
```

The classes support cancellation through the optional CancellationToken parameter.

- For high-performance Socket-based code, [Pipes were introduced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines) to allow handling arbitrary message sizes with minimal allocations by reusing memory buffers, which are passed from one processing step to the next. This saves both memory *and* the time needed to copy data between buffers.
- WebClient was fully replaced by HttpClient. In fact, WebClient and the HttpWebRequest class are simply compatibility wrappers over HttpClient now. HttpClient is thread-safe and asynchronous, using sockets and pipelines to offer far better performance than WebClient:

```
HttpClient _client=new HttpClient(...);

...
async Task<string> GetThatPage(string someUrl)
{
   var page=await _client.GetStringAsync(someUrl);
   ....
}
```

In .NET 6, `Parallel.ForEachAsync` makes it trivial to make multiple asynchronous requests concurrently :

```
var urls=new List<string>();

...
await Parallel.ForEach(urls,async url=>{
    var page=_client.GetStringAsync(url);
    var fileName=CalculateNameFrom(url);
    await File.WrileAllTextAsync(fileName,page);
});
```

The default encoding in .NET (Core) is UTF8.

- SmptClient itself is [obsolete and its documentation page suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-5.0#remarks) using open source clients like [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) instead.
- Asynchronous pings can be sent using [SendPingAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync?view=net-6.0)

```
var reply=await ping.SendPingAsync(someIP);
```

---

**Original Answer (2012)**

Stephen Toub discusses this topic for .NET 4.5 in "[Awaiting Socket Operations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/awaiting-socket-operations/)". With a bit of work you can use the same technique for .NET 4.

Instead of using callbacks, you can use the Task Parallel Library to [simplify asynchronous calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/tpl-and-traditional-async-programming?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Using the TPL you can convert all socket operations and callbacks to tasks that call the operations and process the results.

Tasks can be composed very easily using methods like ContinueWith to execute the next task in a chain only when the first one finishes.

Tasks are executed using threads from the thread pool so you don't have to concern yourself with threading.

TPL already provides a way to create tasks from pairs  of BeginXXX/EndXXX functions, or IAsyncResult objects. If your socket library provides those, you can start using Tasks right away.

To work with events, you can use the TaskCompletionSource from the Task Parallel Library to create a task that will start when you call the socket method and complete only when the appropriate event is raised. The technique is described in "[Tasks and the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern/)"

The [ParallelExtensionsExtras](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/samples/parallel-programming-extensions-extras-cs/) library uses this technique to provide asynchronous method versions for [WebClient, SmtpClient and Ping](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-16-async-tasks-for-webclient-smtpclient-and-ping/).

Using the code from "Tasks and the EAP", you could write extension methods for your Socket class like this:

```
public static Task ConnectTask( this Socket socket, object address) 
{ 
    var tcs = CreateSource(address); 
    socket.ConnectCompleted += 
        (sender, e) => TransferCompletion(tcs, e, () => e.Result, null); 
    socket.ConnectAsync(address, tcs); 
    return tcs.Task; 
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var connectTask=mySocket.ConnectTask(myaddress);
connectTask.ContinueWith(t=> { ... });
```

Things become even easier in .NET 4.5. The async/await keywords allow you to do away with the ContinueWith calls and write code that looks very similar to its synchronous version. You can check "[Awaiting Socket Operations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/awaiting-socket-operations/)" for extensions specifically for Sockets.

Comment: TaskCompletionSource sounds perfect. The socket library only exposes events (no Begin/EndXxxx methods). Many thanks.

Comment: @panagiotis Kanavos please update your links,none of them is working

Comment: The links in this answer are broken and makes this useless.

Comment: @Quade2002 Microsoft reorganized its blog sites some years back breaking everyone's links. Things have changed a *lot* in the last 9 years though. Socket has asynchronous task-based methods now, SmptClient and WebClient are obsolete.

Comment: I was looking for event driven code, not socket code.  That's what the title was about and the kind of examples I was looking for, thus, it's extra useless then.  The 'why' things changed does not really matter, There's just simply nothing here to use.

Comment: @Quade2002 perhaps you misunderstood what the question was about? The question asked how to use asynchronous event-driven code. That's also called the EAP pattern. The answer since 2012 is to convert the event to a `Task` by using a TaskCompletionSource and use `async/await`. That's what the links explain. The links now work. Did you try them?

Comment: The result came from a search I was doing trying to learn event driven code, not sockets.  The title is "How to wrap event-driven code with callbacks?" and there's nothing about sockets in that.  However, my App I am writing will include a network connection, so, along with the UI update threading issue I need to look up, will be useful after all.  Thank you for updating the links.  Unless you had said something, I wouldn't have tried them again.  Thank You for that.  Not useful then, useful now, that works.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Quade2002 the question isn't about event driven code. SO is a Q&A site, not a tutorial site. You should try learn.microsoft.com and the C# tutorial sections instead. Events, callbacks and `async/await` are all alternatives

Comment: It's fine, I was looking for event driven examples, and the search engine mistook this for that.  I was looking for examples along the line of delegates and how += assignments for publisher / subscriber models work.   I do need some threading and socket stuff too, and that's why I was fussing, because I realized it was actually answering that question instead.  It was ahead of what I was looking for at the time, and I was going to follow the links bookmark and come back later.  That's how we got here.   Thanks!!  (P.S. was cranky because my caffeine levels were low.)